# How do I listen to two lists within a class in Flutter riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
class QuestionPaperController extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  QuestionPaperController() : super([]);

  Future<void> getAllPapers(WidgetRef ref) async {
    List<String> imgName = ["biology", "chemistry", "maths", "physics"];
    try {
      for (var img in imgName) {
        final imgUrl = await ref.read(firebaseStorageProvider).getImage(img);
        state = [...state, imgUrl!];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}

final questionPaperControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<QuestionPaperController, List<String>>((ref) {
  return QuestionPaperController();
});
```

I want to add another list that its name will stackoverflow for this class and watch it but statenotifier listening another list what can I do?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add one more list to this class

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another instance of the class

```dart
class StackoverflowController extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  /// ...
}

final stackoverflowControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<StackoverflowController, List<String>>((ref) {
  return StackoverflowController();
});
```

and create provider that `watch` the other two

```dart
final otherProvider = Provider<...>((ref) {
  ref.watch(stackoverflowControllerProvider);
  ref.watch(questionPaperControllerProvider );
  return ...;
});
```

**bonus**: you can pass `ref` in class-controller:

```dart
final fizzControllerPr = Provider.autoDispose((ref) => FizzController(ref));

// or use tear-off
final fizzControllerPr1 = Provider.autoDispose(FizzController.new);

/// Class represent controller.
class FizzController {
  FizzController(this._ref);

  final Ref _ref;

  Future<void> getAllPapers() async {
    //...
    final imgUrl = await _ref.read(firebaseStorageProvider).getImage(img);
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the other provider doing here?